# Cannot find realtime updates panel in the new App DashBoard

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

Where can we configure "Subscribing to Realtime Updates" in the new App Dashboard ?
It looks like the following documentation is not aligned with the new App dashboard
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates

thanks

Comment: It's not there in the new one yet, you can use the API to configure subscriptions in the meantime

Answer (score 2):

Payments and Payment subscriptions objects are appears in "Orders" tab: `https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/__appId__/payments/`

But you can't configure actions field (oO)

For configure those fields and other objects, use Graph API.

For example, graph api explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

- set type to `POST`
- remove access_token input's value
- set url `__appID__/subscriptions?access_token=__appID__|__appSecret__&object=payments`
- add field:

  - object: (subscription object - user, payments, permissions, etc)
  - callback_url: your_url
  - verify_token: your_token
  - fields: (for payments `actions,disputes` are required)

**Update**: found, that this, old URL is still work:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/__appID__/realtime?ref=nav
```